# How do I implement pointer-based data structures in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I'm going through Steven S. Skiena's *The Algorithm Design Manual*, and one problem I'm running into is that it mainly uses pointers. I'm using Python, which doesn't have pointers; so, how should I approach implementing a pointer-based data structure in Python?

For example, in chapter 3, some of the exercises include converting a binary tree into a linked list. Both the binary tree and the linked list involve pointers between nodes. What's the Python equivalent of that?

Comment: This is way too broad for Stack Overflow. You need a discussion forum, or a mailing list, not a Q&A site. There's a Community section on python.org that may have relevant links; if not, the main `python-list` mailing list should be a good place to get pointed to a better place.

Comment: But meanwhile, without knowing anything about that book: you can easily build binary trees and linked lists without pointers. For example, a `TreeNode` just has two attributes `left` and `right` that contain other `TreeNode` values. Python doesn't let you directly embed structs in other structs like C (containing is always by reference), and it doesn't let you manually manage the memory (everything is automatically managed), so there's no need for pointers anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: +1. I disagree with abarnert's first comment; this question is very much answerable, as proved by his/her second comment (which should have been an answer).

Comment: @ruakh I disagree with you. This would imply such questions can be asked all the time and can be and are answered in the right depth too. This is not the case. I encountered many questions which tried a similar approach and were dismissed by the community. These type of questions are rather about discussions which are discouraged on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've gone through a lot of this book using Javascript. Part of the fun is translating the ideas into a language you are familiar with. You need to approach it with the understanding that the book is about ideas, not a particular language. However, becoming a *little* familiar with c will really help you understand the examples.

So for example, you are probably unlikely to use linked lists in python the way you would in c, but you can certainly implement them from the examples using classes and object properties that point to other properties.

Consider a simple linked list:

```
class ListItem():
    def __init__(self, val, next = None):
        self.next = next
        self.value = val
```

`self.next` is essentialy a pointer to the next ListItem. Now you can create a linked list with something like:

```
arr = [5, 7, 2, 1, 9, 0, 10, 23]

head = ListItem(10)
current = head
for n in arr:
    item = ListItem(n)
    current.next = item
    current = item
```

And then traverse the list with:

```
pointer = head
while(pointer):
    print(pointer.value)
    pointer = pointer.next
```

You can also do a linked-list style insert and it will look a lot like the c code:

```
#insert 'inserted_node' before first list item with value 1
inserted_node = ListItem('inserted')
pointer = head
while(pointer):
    if pointer.next.value == 1:
        inserted_node.next = pointer.next
        pointer.next = inserted_node
        break
    pointer = pointer.next
```

It's a terrific book and worth going through even if you're not doing it in c or some other low level language. And even if you spend time with data structures you normally wouldn't go to in python, doing the translation  will make you a better python programmer.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you very much Mark_M. Do you think it would make sense to first try the problems in C++ first (or C), then attempt an alternative python solution?

Comment: @user9028381 I personally haven't done that. I felt like I got more out of it translating to a language I knew rather than fighting with compiler errors. But I have never done any serious c or c++ work, so it would have added a lot of work for me.

Comment: +1. A python reference is basically a pointer. The main difference is you can’t do pointer arithmetic. Which doesn’t matter for purposes of working through an algorithms book. @user9028381: Using C or C++ for this will incur a big learning curve. I’m a former C programmer and I would think twice about this, I’d only undertake it if I specifically wanted to refresh my C or C++ skills.